# How do you define pattern-specific variables for makefile pattern rules containing a patterned prerequisite?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I understand that you can define pattern-specific variables for rules with no prerequisites, like this:

```
%.o: var = 2
```

This will set variable `var` to 2 for recipes that apply to all targets ending in .o.  This is clearly stated in the [GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern_002dspecific). But how do you define a pattern-specific variable for pattern rules that contain a pattern prerequisite, like this:

```
%.o: %.c
```

Say I have this section of makefile:

```
%.o: %.c
    (recipe here)

%.o: %.b
    (recipe here)
```

I want to define a pattern-specific variable only for the `%.o: %.b` rule, but I don't see how to do it (if it's even possible).  I'd like to do something like this, but of course it doesn't work:

```
%.o: %.c
    (recipe here)

%.o: %.b: var = 2
    (recipe here)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only set variable for **targets**, not rules. `%.o: %b` is a rule where `%.o` is a target pattern (hence the "pattern-specific" name).

The usual way to solve this is ether hard coding values in the recipes or using rule-specific flags (maybe `CVAR` and `BVAR` in your case).

**EDIT:** Scratch that. Came up with a workaround.

It can be done by leveraging variables' recursive evaluation.

```
all: a.o b.o c.o

$(shell touch a.xx b.yy c.zz)

##
# Create rule-specific variable... rules
#
# @param 1 Target.
# @param 2 Prerequisite.
# @param 3 Variable name.
# @param 4 Variable value.
#
rule-var = $(eval $(rule-var-body))
define rule-var-body
$1: private $3 = $$(if $$(<:$2=),$(or $(value rule-var-$1-$3),$(value $3)),$4)
$2: $3 = $4
rule-var-$1-$3 = $$(if $$(<:$2=),$(or $(value rule-var-$1-$3),$(value $3)),$4)
endef

VAR = $(VAR_DEFAULT)

# Declare couple of test values
$(call rule-var,%.o,%.x,VAR,x-value)
$(call rule-var,%.o,%.y,VAR,y-value)
VAR_DEFAULT := z-value

ECHO_RULE_RECIPE = @echo -e '$@: $^\t(VAR = $(VAR))'

%.o: %.x
    $(ECHO_RULE_RECIPE)
%.o: %.y
    $(ECHO_RULE_RECIPE)
%.o: %.z
    $(ECHO_RULE_RECIPE)
%.x: %.xx
    $(ECHO_RULE_RECIPE)
%.y: %.yy
    $(ECHO_RULE_RECIPE)
%.z: %.zz
    $(ECHO_RULE_RECIPE)
```

The output is:

```
a.x: a.xx       (VAR = x-value)
a.o: a.x        (VAR = x-value)
b.y: b.yy       (VAR = y-value)
b.o: b.y        (VAR = y-value)
c.z: c.zz       (VAR = z-value)
c.o: c.z        (VAR = z-value)
```

The brains of the operation is macro `rule-var`. It will wrap variable value in a prerequisite matching `if-else` expression. The expression is also saved in `rule-var-$1-$3` variable for other rule-specific values.

`$$(if $$(<:$2=),$(or $(value rule-var-$1-$3),$(value $3)),$4)` deobfuscation:

`$$(if $$(<:$2=),` will test first prerequisite value (`$<`) by replacing it's pattern (`$2`) with empty string.

- If pattern **doesn't** match, use `$(or $(value rule-var-$1-$3),$(value $3))`. This is a workaround for global variable shadowing. In your example `%.o: %.c` doesn't have `var` declared so it *should* use global value but both rules share the same target, it's not visible. Both are referenced by value and single `$` expands the expression during variable substitution phase. So the result is neat and `or` free.

  - Use `$(value rule-var-$1-$3)` if it's nonzero. That is function has been called before for this target and variable name.
  - Otherwise use variable's global value (`$(value $3)`).
- Otherwise use the value provided (`$4`).

Unfortunately, when inherited, this if-else monstrosity won't expand properly so it's declared as `private` and fixed with a straightforward second rule.

In this example the following 3 rules will be declared.

```
%.o: private VAR = $(if $(<:%.y=),$(if $(<:%.x=),$(VAR_DEFAULT),x-value),y-value)
%.y: VAR = y-value
%.x: VAR = x-value
```

**Limitations**

Even with a workaround, variable's global counterpart is still shadowed. If you need a default value, assign it **before** calling `rule-var`. Global value is copied as a part of the rule-specific variable but not expanded until use.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the syntax, but I'm struggling a little.  The line `$$(if $$(<:$2=),$(or $(value rule-var-$3),$(value $3)),$4)` is throwing me.  I think it boils down to `if prereq1:prereq1=` but I haven't seen that syntax before, or the ensuing one starting with `or`.  Can you please explain that line a little more?

Comment: @smeep There you go.

Comment: You clearly know your stuff.  I'm still working my way through your answer, but while doing so may have found another solution, which I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution, although it could get a little difficult to read depending on how many prerequisite comparisons are made.  Perhaps there's a way to refactor it.

```
# Return 1 if prerequisite ends in `.c`.
# Return 2 if prerequisite ends in `.b`.
build-var = $(if $(filter %.c,$<),1,$(if $(filter %.b,$<),2))

%.o: private var = $(build-var)
%.o: %.c
    (recipe here)

%.o: %.b
    (recipe here)
```

The instruction `var = $(build-var)` will be invoked for any target that ends in `.o`.  But when `build-var` is expanded, its value comes from examining the end of the prerequisite to see what type of file it is.

The `if` statement evaluates to true if its first argument is a non-empty string, and `filter` returns a non-empty string if, in my example, the prerequisite contains `.c`.  So, walking through the `build-var` line, if the prerequisite (denoted by the automatic variable `$<`) ends in `.c`, then return the value `1`.  Else, start a second `if` statement that returns the value `2` if the prerequisite ends in `.b`.  If the prerequisite doesn't end in either `.c` or `.b` then build-var is set to nothing (an empty string).